# Images inside a display:flex item partially distorted or cut off

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently building a horizontal scroller for an image gallery.

The scroller works so far, but unfortunately the images are partially distorted or part of it is cut off.

I suspect that it has something to do with Flexbox ...

**Here you can see the code of the scroll slider (markup + scss)**
https://jsfiddle.net/3cdkxbvm/

```css
.scroll-slider-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
 .scroll-slider-title svg {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
 .scroll-slider-title a {
  color: inherit;
}
 .scroll-slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
 .scroll-slider .scroll-slider-pane {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2rem 0 3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
 .scroll-slider .scroll-slider-track {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
 .image-gallery {
  display: flex;
}
 .image-gallery .image-gallery-item {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: auto;
}
 .image-gallery .image-gallery-item img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-slider" id="js_image_gallery"> 
  
  <div class="scroll-slider-pane">
   <div class="scroll-slider-track">
    <div class="image-gallery">
       
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <img src="https://s1.waazz.com/thumbs/l800/83/1083_af8cbfd999d37bbac86691e9c5ffb76f">
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <img src="https://s1.waazz.com/thumbs/p800/84/1084_72a6840640a8650cc01f41d55346973c">
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <img src="https://s1.waazz.com/thumbs/p800/85/1085_5f18260d83ea0790be5a8029b7638872">
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <img src="https://s1.waazz.com/thumbs/p800/86/1086_66daf815df8570e11564f3426c074f3c">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the all-important question:
Why are my images partially distorted or part of it is cut off.? And how can I solve this?
It is important that the pictures always have the same height. However, the width may vary depending on the picture.

**Here you can find a working fiddle where you can see the problem with the images.** I have tested it in the latest Chrome version.
https://jsfiddle.net/3cdkxbvm/

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: as you may noticed, the code snippet doesn't support SASS so better convert it to CSS or remove the snippet

Comment: not sure why you have width: 100% and width: auto in your img , also , the snippet shows nothing so check that out to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

`HTML`

```
<div class="scroll-slider-track">
  <div class="image-gallery">
    <div class="image-gallery-item">
      <img src="https://s1.waazz.com/thumbs/l800/83/1083_af8cbfd999d37bbac86691e9c5ffb76f">
    </div>
    <div class="image-gallery-item">
      <img src="https://s1.waazz.com/thumbs/p800/84/1084_72a6840640a8650cc01f41d55346973c">
    </div>
    <div class="image-gallery-item">
      <img src="https://s1.waazz.com/thumbs/p800/85/1085_5f18260d83ea0790be5a8029b7638872">
    </div>
    <div class="image-gallery-item">
      <img src="https://s1.waazz.com/thumbs/p800/86/1086_66daf815df8570e11564f3426c074f3c">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`SCSS`

```
.scroll-slider-track {
  // do not set a height for this container
  // because the horizontal scroller also needs
  // space and this varies in every browser
  width: 800px; // set the width you need
  overflow: auto;
}

.image-gallery {
  height: 300px; // height of the gallery images, set one you like best
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.image-gallery-item {
  flex: 0 0 auto; // turn off shrink and grow behavior
  // needed, so the img element can calculate its height
  // using a  value in percent:
  height: 100%;

  &:not(:first-child) { // addressing all items except the first one
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }

  img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto; // this will keep the image ratio intact
    flex: 0 0 auto; // turn off shrink and grow behavior
    display: block; // making sure, no whitespace or line-height issues occur
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Artur
Thank you for your answer! Helped me a lot :) In my case the problem was the unset height in .image-gallery-item. As soon as i set the height to 100%, it worked.
Do you have any idea how i get the images all the same height? here you can find another fiddle with the current state: https://jsfiddle.net/3cdkxbvm/1/

Comment: Hi, nice to hear, that I could help you. I addressed this already in the code I posted. If you compare my code with your fiddle you will find that you miss one important line: `.image-gallery {... height: 300px; }` This should solve your problem. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-right or add margin-right more than 1rem